# How to manipulate occurrences of tags <br /> and <hr />

Tags: php

I need to manipulate the occurrence of tags when they appear in the page.

The conditions are:

- If the tag br appears more than 2 times in a row, this occurrence must be replaced for 2 tags br
- If the tag hr appears more than 1 time in a row, this occurrence must be replaced for 1 tag

This will show how it must work. 
This is just an example.

```
<div>
    <p>
        Text 1
        <br />
        <br />
        Text 2
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Text 3
        <hr />
        <hr />
        Text 4  
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Text 5
        <hr />
        Text 6
        <hr />
        <hr />
        <hr />
    </p>
</div>
```

It should stay that way:

```
<div>
    <p>
        Text 1
        <br />
        <br />
        Text 2
        <br />
        <br />
        Text 3
        <hr />
        Text 4  
        <br />
        <br />
        Text 5
        <hr />
        Text 6
        <hr />
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I do it?

I have tried of many ways. before, I've used the function str_replace to create a function for me.

But after, I thought that preg_replace is a best way. **My problem, is that I don't know how to detect the number of the occurrence of the tag.** My function is below:

helper.php

```
function formatText($text){
    $text = preg_replace("/(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/", "<br /><br />", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/(<hr\s*\/?>\s*)+/", "<hr /><br />", $text);

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: You write code. Tip: http://php.net/dom

Comment: You need to show your PHP code, what you've tried so far. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Ah ok, just a minute

Comment: it's there people

Comment: I looked the answers os this question, but it's a little different of my situation. It didn't solve my problem